# How to split curve after mesh to curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I want to split the curve after the `Mesh to Curve` node. I need to trim the curve at the corners, but when I apply the node, it starts at a different point. Any idea how I can solve this?

1. I'd like to trim from corners like on example image but it joins curve.
2. Does not trim at all
3. Correct trim

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please be so kind, and always try to clarify your question with a picture and describe it as precisely as possible. In my opinion, your questions are not precise enough and everyone who tries to help you understands something different...

Comment: Sorry for that. Update resolves the issue

Comment: To make it more obvious. I'd like to do a shape of building and filter elements like balcony- flat horizontal edges, angled edges - roof, vertical corner edges- details of corners, bottom edges. All edges should have different instances and should be trimable from vertexes. It should be it... Thank You for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to split curve after mesh to curve?

Unfortunately, this does not work.

A curve cannot be divided just like that. You could do some calculations and place new curves, but the following suggestion is easier than that:

[image]

[image]

Divide the edges of the mesh before you convert it into curves.

1. Select the parts that are important to you with the node `Capture Attribute` even before you apply this mechanism. Only then you can use this data later.
2. Then apply the node `Extrude Mesh` and enter 0 as value for *Offset Scale*.
3. Then split the edges with the node `Split Edges`.
4. Another crucial part: Separate only the *Top Faces* that the node `Mesh Extrude` gives you from the rest of the mesh.
5. Finally, apply the `Mesh to Curve` node.

*To make this more visible, in this example I also scale the edges with the node `Scale Elements` and apply `Mesh to Curve` only to the previously selected horizontal edges.*

[image]

Comment: Thank You, work great !!!